# Deploying socket.io on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-app-engine

How can I deploy and run socket.io server written in Node.js on App Engine. Is it supported? If not what alternatives can I use

Here is my socket:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('send message', function(data) {
        console.log('sending room post', data.room);
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('conversation private post', data.message)
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is now possible as of Jan 2019 with Google App Engine Flex. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity). It even has all the code you need.

tldr; you need to use GAE flex and add the below to your app.yaml:

```
network:
  session_affinity: true
```